Filling does not work with ListLinePlot
I have the following code to generate a plot that fills between the two curves. The filling didn't show up. Please help.
data1 = {{200.`, -0.005304268318058835`}, {191.66666666666666`, \
-0.006834686952302141`}, {183.33333333333334`, 
    0.00944200446915218`}, {175.`, 
    0.009781375781821457`}, {166.66666666666666`, 
    0.015342367897367416`}, {158.33333333333334`, 
    0.030634597943377036`}, {150.`, -0.005867676448746067`}, \
{141.66666666666666`, 0.05482080672731302`}, {133.33333333333334`, 
    0.08581713514723843`}, {125.`, 0.020441852540827744`}};
data2 = {{200.`, -0.03439560955090365`}, {191.66666666666666`, \
-0.023436621646363794`}, {183.33333333333334`, -0.0615511709981207`}, \
{175.`, -0.052032724603167595`}, {166.66666666666666`, \
-0.023548005821790546`}, {158.33333333333334`, \
-0.004797092101037494`}, {150.`, -0.033126627990196236`}, \
{141.66666666666666`, -0.009117111306033605`}, {133.33333333333334`, \
-0.008794559396553575`}, {125.`, -0.05683399429203467`}};

ListLinePlot[
 {
  data1,
  data2
  },
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}
 ]


Use ListLinePlot[{Sort@data1, Sort@data2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] so that the X values are in ascending order.

I see, it worked now. Thank you!

ListLinePlot[Reverse /@ {data1, data2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
